# WinSock: Remove data from socket

Tags: c++, winsock2

I want to receive data from a socket without specifing a buffer. So I just want to remove x bytes from the incoming data buffer.

I have the following code (truncated):

```
recv(gSocket, NULL, userDataLength, 0);
```

But when I execute the code above the return value of `recv()` is `SOCKET_ERROR` and `WSAGetLastError()` returns `WSAECONNABORTED`. Furthermore my connection get's closed.

Question: Is it not possible, to use the receive function for removing data from the RX buffer of the socket?

Comment: Where does it say that the buffer pointer can be null?

Comment: Nowhere. But I thought it is possible because it's possible on other socket libraries.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such libraries but in any case that's a *non sequitur.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to receive data from a socket without specifing a buffer.

Sorry, but that is simply not possible.  You must provide a buffer to receive the bytes.  If you don't want to use the bytes, simply discard the buffer after you have read into it.

> I just want to remove x bytes from the incoming data buffer.

There is no API for that.  You must read the bytes into a valid buffer.  What you do with that buffer afterwards is up to you.

> when I execute the code above the return value of `recv()` is `SOCKET_ERROR` and `WSAGetLastError()` returns `WSAECONNABORTED`.

I would have expected `WSAEFAULT` instead.

> Is it not possible, to use the receive function for removing data from the RX buffer of the socket?

Sure, it is possible.  You simply have to read the bytes into a buffer, even if it is just a temporary buffer, eg:

```
int ignoreBytes(SOCKET sock, int numBytes)
{
    u_char buf[256];
    while (numBytes > 0)
    {
        int numRead = recv(sock, (char*)buf, min(sizeof(buf), numBytes), 0);
        if (numRead <= 0)
            return numRead;
        numBytes -= numRead;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

```
ignoreBytes(gSocket, userDataLength);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have written my own function to remove / ignore bytes (similar to your code).